# Как произвести регистрацию нового пользователя в мобильном приложения через Google Play

Tags: google-play, регистрация

Какими способами можно произвести  регистрацию нового пользователя в  мобильном  приложения  IOS И Android, через Google Play с  подгрузкой  данных таких как: Имя, Фамилия, Email, Аватар.

Пример: https://yadi.sk/i/5uTUf6J63KjkYR

Comment: Смотрите официальную документацию для [Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) и [iOS](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating)

Comment: Ссылку  не моли  бы скинуть,  был  бы  очень  благодарен.

Comment: Так в первом комменте и есть ссылки. Кликайте на слова Android и iOS